# Need to import data in various cells from multiple sheets, based on text typed in a reference cell in MS Excel

Tags: excel

this is what my first sheet looks like

```
Vessel Name
```

S.No.           Issued  Due Date    Last Date   Due Date
    BV No.
    Certificates
1   Hull
2   Machinery
3   Load Line

my other sheets have the data listed in them in following format:
S.No.                           Issued    Due Date  Last Date   Due Date
    Name        Taybah
    BV No.       09678W
    Certificates
1   Hull                       28.5.07    22.1.12
2   Machinery                  28.5.07    22.1.12
3   Load Line              28.5.07    22.1.12
    Name        Khawlah
    BV No.       09542T
    Certificates
1   Hull                       28.5.07    22.1.12
2   Machinery                  28.5.07    22.1.12
3   Load Line              28.5.07    22.1.12
    Name        Ghanim
    BV No.       09273L
    Certificates
1   Hull                       28.5.07    22.1.12
2   Machinery                  28.5.07    22.1.12
3   Load Line              28.5.07    22.1.12

I want to just type the name in the **cell next to vessel name**(in the 1st sheet) and i want all the corresponding data to be reflected in the various columns on the first sheet for the corresponding name.
please help me as i am really losing my sanity trying to find a solution.

thanking you in advance

Comment: It is hard to understand the format of your data - can you edit your post and start each line of data with 4 spaces to preserve spacing and make sure cells in one column look aligned?

Answer (score 1):

Since the data to display is in the exact same place in each data table and the same "distance" away from the vessel name, you should read up and use the OFFSET() function to accomplish this.

You would use an INDEX/MATCH in the first parameter to exactly spot the address of the vessel name, then edit the second and third paramters to offset however many rows/columns you need for each cell.

For instance, the first HULL value (28.5) appears to be 3 rows down and one column to the right of the vessel name.